# Error On Redirection Code PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I used the code:

```
<?php
header("Location: /site"); // to redirect to /site directory
?>
```

It worked perfectly on XAMPP but Doen't go well for Bluehost since the host doesn't redirect to the page.

Any Help for fixing this?
PS: Changing the path to another also doesn't helped me either.

Comment: Have you tried to do any debugging? For example are you using something like FireBug to look at the headers you're getting back, or are you looking through your error logs?  Technically you're supposed to send an entire URL for a redirect, not just the path, but it usually works anyway.  It's possible your host had disabled the header function, or it could be any of a number of other things.

Comment: Yeah, I think so, but since it's renowned host, i don't think the host has disabled the feature. and thing about path, i already tried for redirecting to filename like index.php but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below,

```
<?php
header("Location: site/"); // to redirect to site directory
return;
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to actually address whatever issue the OP is having, what's more the redirect will be to the wrong location of the script isn't in the same directory as the sites directory

Comment: The Problem is not of the directory. The host doesn't redirect to any page. It just ignores the header tag.

Comment: @GordonM he has mention that it's working fine on XAMPP  an we assume that he has moved the files properly...as you have commented on his post saying for debugging, i don't think if he knows about debugging that he would ever post a question like this..Think from the users side rather than thinking as a developer always..

Comment: @Aadarsha try the above code..insert `die();`  immediately after you call `header`

Comment: @jlocker well you guessed right. I am not that much expert but your any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @jlocker I tried that die(); and exit(); but it just kills the code below but doesn't redirects!

Comment: @Aadarsha try including `return;`

Comment: Can you elaborate that? I am not that much expert on PHP! I recently(6 months ago) started to learn PHP!

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: Well, that code didn't helped me too. :/ Now i am thinking why I used Bluehost! I think I need to consult Host officials :D

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using a editor there should not be any space between `<?PHP`
   which made the header function not work sometimes this space causes the problem.

Comment: I hope not, since the code below are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Below one is the way to do this

```
<script>
window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('paste the location') ?>"
</script>
```

or

```
 window.location.href = "<?php echo url ?>"
```

Comment: Well, I prefer not to use the client side scripting.